# C# application possibly not disposing properly

Tags: c#

I'm writing a Class Library in C# as an add-on to another application that provides an API.  Essentially, the application is set to execute the code in my Class Library upon changing a specific text field in the application.  I'm finding that after I change that field once, changing any other text field also triggers my code to run and I cannot figure out why.

The Class Library has a function executed by the application.  Essentially, I'm connecting to a SQL Database, calling a Windows Form to show, then disposing of everything.  I find that by removing the SqlConnection, the issue does not occur.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

```
SqlConnection myConnection;

myConnection = new SqlConnection("user id=" + Username + ";" +
"password=" + Password + ";" +
"server=" + Server + ";" +
"database=" + DBName + ";" +
"connection timeout=" + ConnectionTimeout + ";"
);

myConnection.Open();





string currentValue = htableData["Test"].ToString().Trim();

if (!(String.IsNullOrEmpty(currentValue)))
{

    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Form1 form = new Form1();
    Application.Run(form);

    form.Dispose();


}


myConnection.Dispose();
```

Comment: *by removing the `SqlConnection`* - you mean, when you dispose it, it doesn't occur? Where is the event handler which triggers this change? And is this `Application.Run` code really inside the `if`? Where is that code placed?

Answer (score 0):

> Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

This isn't quite what you asked about, but it is not good practice to call `Dispose` explicitly. It is best to use `using` blocks instead.

```
SqlConnection connection;
using (connection = ... ) {
  // use the connection

} // connection is automatically disposed (and error handling is done for you)
```

Ideally, you should also use the same pattern on the `form`

Answer (score 0):

```
using(SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(
    "user id=" + Username + ";" +
    "password=" + Password + ";" +
    "server=" + Server + ";" +
    "database=" + DBName + ";" +
    "connection timeout=" + ConnectionTimeout + ";")
){

    myConnection.Open();    

    string currentValue = htableData["Test"].ToString().Trim();

    if (!(String.IsNullOrEmpty(currentValue)))
    {

        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Form1 form = new Form1();
        Application.Run(form);

        form.Dispose();
    }

    myConnection.Close();

}
```

Comment: What's the difference? `Close` and `Dispose` are functionally equivalent in a `SqlConnection`. [Edit] Also, after adding the `using` clause, the `Close` call is redundant.

Comment: @Groo I'm not working with ADO.NET for about 4 or 5 years. Actually I forgot most practices. Are you sure? If yep, I'll remove `Close`

Answer (score 0):

You are not providing enough code to tell why it is called twice. But I do have a couple of comments to make.

1. This is not the correct way to display a form within and already running application that already displays other UI elements. The correct way is `form.Show()` or `form.ShowDialog()`. I guess the latter in your case. Avoid calling `EnableVisualStyles` and `SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault` as well.
2. To ensure the correct disposal of things (especially when exceptions occur), you could make use of the using statement, even though I don't think that this is the cause of your problem. Here is a nice showcase: [Understanding the 'using' statement in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6564/Understanding-the-using-statement-in-C)
3. Again, it will not solve your problem, but a more elegant way of creating your connection string would be to use the `SqlConnectionStringBuilder`, instead of concatenating the strings. Here is how: [How to use SqlConnectionStringBuilder in C#](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Blogs/13861/how-to-use-sqlconnectionstringbuilder-in-C-Sharp.aspx)